# Populating a PHP variable from a form post

Tags: php

I am trying to pass over a value from an HTML form.  Basically I have 1 text box in the form, and the form posts to itself.  I am using this to check to see if a coupon code is valid.  If I enter a valid coupon in to the text field and hit the enter key on keyboard, it calls the page (posts to same page), passes over the value in the text box but doesn’t apply the discount.   however if I enter in a valid coupon code but instead of hitting the enter key on the keyboard and hit the submit button it calls the page and passes over the value and coupon code gets set

I have used some debugging tools to capture what is being sent over, and it is sending the value over through a POST.

THIS ONLY SEEMS TO BE AN ISSUE IN IE.  FIREFOX, CHROME AND OTHER BROWSERS WORK FINE.  I TRIED BOTH IE8 AND IE7 AND NEITHER WOULD WORK.

I would think that it should still apply the discount regardless if I hit the enter key or use the submit button.  Does anyone have any ideas what I can change to correct this and make this work in IE?  The page us coded in HTML and PHP.

Comment: We'll need some code to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field to your form, like

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value=1>
```

Then on your page, instead of performing your code if the submit button was pressed, check to see if

```
$_POST['submitted']==1
```

Comment: You should not use $_REQUEST in my opinion as it aggregates $_POST, $_GET, and $_COOKIE. Use only what your form is using:  `if($_POST['submitted'] == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your input is of `type="image"`.  For whatever ungodly reason, IE only sends the coordinates of an image click submit rather than its value.  Therefor the "enter" key will never give you the value of the submit image in IE.  The solution is either to change it to `type="submit"` and give it a background-image, or put a hidden input in your form to indicate submission.

Answer (score 0):

Some example code would be nice, but in the meantime, have you tried dumping $_Post?

```
<?php
    print_r($_Post);
?>
```

This will return an array of all the stuff submitted in the form, so you can have an idea what it's expecting.

Also, how are you calculating the discount?
Something to consider, instead of resubmitting the whole page, is look into AJAX HTTPRequest
Then you can have them type in a code, hit a lookup button, and the page passes it off to another page where the calculation is done, then the value is returned to the first page. That way you don't even have the annoyance of reloading everything and it looks a lot smoother.